# How to make nouveau and nvidia drivers work both at the same time

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, nouveau, gpu-driver

Does anybody know how to make nvidia and nouveau drivers work together with 2 different graphics cards ? Or 2 different versions of nvidia driver. I need this because one of graphic adapter supported by 440 driver, another(older) supported by legacy 330 driver. I can't install both in usual way(maybe there is another way). If I set 440 driver for newer card with drivers-manager, options for another card become inactive so I can't set anything :-(

I am also curious how the driver-manager set these drivers because it doesn't touch xorg.conf. Which configs does it modify?

My OS is 20.04, kernel 5.4.0-29-lowlatency

```
$ sudo lshw -C display

*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G96C [GeForce 9500 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:76000000-76ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff memory:74000000-75ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:77000000-7707ffff

*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP108 [GeForce GT 1030]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:72000000-72ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff memory:70000000-71ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way.

Comment: I am ready to try hard one if there is any.

Comment: I am not aware of any, theoretically it can be develop by `nouveau` source code modification. But I am not sure it is feasible, because the proprietary drivers are closed-source.